# How to copy all files from a folder into one file to another folder using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, glob

Is there any way to copy specific lines of files from a folder into just one file in another folder?

example:`users/catalina/Desktop/BA/folder1`

```
 **file1.info**

    hello:1

    hi:2

    -----  
lll:43
```

.

```
**file2.info**

hello:133
hi:244
----- 
lll:4311
```

expected file something like this: `users/catalina/Desktop/BA/folder2`

```
output.info

1  133
2  244
```

this is my try :

```
import glob    
read_files = glob.glob("/*.info")
with open("result.info", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: The answer is: yes! However: a) this site does not provide code writing services. b) what should the rules be? Take nothing from file1 and take everything from file2? What is the relationship between the two? Why is `hello:1` and `hi:2` ignored? Why is `lll` ignored? Which files should be processed? Which files should not be processed?

Comment: Ideally you want some python written already.  Then if you have a bug or can't figure out some syntax step we can help.